# change html for just parent category in archive page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates

how can i add a parent to content-product-cat.php in the wordpress template
I want to separation product category of product in  archive-product.php
how can i do that?
thanks for helping

I just can edit loop-start.php but it add parent for all
I want add parent just category not products